# How to detect ajax cross domain request in php

Tags: php, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

For the normal ajax request I use:

```
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'
```

But this don't work with cross domain request.

How can I do?

Comment: What are you trying to get from the other domain? HTML? JSON? Other data?

Comment: Use jQuery.get() with JSONP: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: No, what I want is detect in php the ajax request! But if it's cross domain the code above don't work!

Comment: If you're the one serving the page, you should be able to tell that the page's domain does not match that of the AJAX request. It's a simple string comparison.

Comment: @Diodeus Thank you! I use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], maybe is the better solution.

Comment: You cannot currently detect that information without adding some parametric sugar into the request which helps the intelligent PHP engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit2:**
If you're using jQuery.ajax function in this way:

```
var request = $.ajax({
url: "http://somesite.com/somescript.php?somevar=somevalue",
dataType: "jsonp",
jsonp: 'callback',
success: function(data) {
alert('Done!');
}
});
```

Then you can check the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable, or simply `$_GET['callback']` and `$_GET['_']`. The REQUEST_URI will look like this:

/somescript.php?somevar=somevalue&callback=jQuery172028849187534502896_1333494007273&_=1333494443880

**Edit: The answer below is to find out if it is cross-domain or not, not checking if it is AJAX**

The answer to the question "How to determine if an ajax-call is from a different domain" is this:

I'm using the jQuery.ajax call, and for me using the variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` works fine.

If I'm using a page on my local computer, this superglobal returns an empty string.

If I'm using a page on the internet, the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` returns the URL of the page that made the ajax call. So checking the value of this can tell you what you need to know.

Comment: I realize that I probably misunderstood the question. I assumed the question was how to detect if an Ajax-request comes from a different domain or not. Now I interpret the question as "How to detect if it is an ajax-request or not".

Comment: I have now edited the post, big time, to improve the answer. This time by answering the correct question.

Comment: The value of $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] might also be interesting to investigate. It's different depending on if Ajax is used or if you access somescript.php directly.

Answer (score 1):

To detect Ajax and CrossDomain Request try this:

```
function is_ajax_request() {
    return isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] : false === 'XMLHttpRequest';
}


function check_cross_domain($referrer, $host) {
    $referrer = str_ireplace( 'www.', '', parse_url( $referrer, PHP_URL_HOST ) );
    $pattern = '/' . $host . '/';
    return preg_match($pattern, $referrer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] to get the request domain

Answer (score -1):

you can use php's getallheaders() function. you can check the host entry

Comment: That's just gonna check if it's cross-domain or not, not if it is an Ajax-request.

Comment: if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
  $isAjaxRequest = true;
 } and getallheaders() which tell about the current request details. So using both of them can resolve your issue.

Comment: The problem is that $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] is empty when it comes to cross-domain Ajax requests. I tried it myself and it says so in the question: Using that doesn't work for cross-domain requests.