# PHP - check if cross domain AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

For same domain AJAX, I can use this:

```
 if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'):
```

But the statement above return `false` when it's a cross-domain AJAX. What's the right conditional statement to detect that?

Thanks

I have checked [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997714/how-to-detect-ajax-cross-domain-request-in-php?rq=1) but it doesn't seem to offer good answer

Comment: That totally depends on how you're performing the AJAX request. In any case, I'd just set up a specifically named endpoint, something like `/some/service/jsonp`

Comment: @Phil yeah adding different URL for the cross-domain AJAX would be the easiest way, but I'm trying to look for cleaner way (having one `index.php` that handle all request). the `AJAX` request is just getting a single row from database though

Comment: You could use URL rewriting to rewrite `/some/service/(.*)` to `index.php?format=$1` or even just use `PATHINFO`, eg `index.php/some/service/formatType`